# Use a 20 sided die and a 6 sided die to represent number 1-45 with equal probability

Tags: probability, dice

I wonder if anyone could help me with this question:

> Use a 20 sided die and a 6 sided die to represent all numbers from 1-45 with equal probability.

Also, it is okay to use one die repeatedly as long as the probability of getting each of 1-45 are equal.

I tried different ways such as use the 1-4 from the 6 sided die to represent the tenth bit and the 1-9 to represent the 1th bit...but none of them really works. I would appreciate if anyone could give me a good hint. Thanks

Comment: Can we use two remainders $a,\,b$ of the $6$-die modulo $3$ and one remainder $c$ of the $20$-die modulo $5$ to form $(3a+b)\cdot 5 + c$?

Comment: Hint: can you find $p$ and $q$ so that $20^{p}\cdot6^{q}$ is divisible by 45?

Comment: But would p,q such that 20^p*6^9 has the same probability?

Comment: The best approach is construct the numbers via digits of numeric system. Trying to do it via factoring or sums is a real pain, if not impossible.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Roll the $20$-sided die once and the $6$-sided die twice, recording the three outcomes in order. Then use the fact that $20\cdot6\cdot6=720=16\cdot45$. (This approach requires that you make a reference table or else keep a *lot* of information in your head.)

**Added:** A more efficient alternative is to roll the $6$-sided die twice, reducing each outcome modulo $3$, and interpret the result as a two-digit number in base $3$. This gives you an integer in the range $\{0,1,\ldots,8\}$ with uniform probability. Roll the $20$-sided die once and reduce modulo $5$ to get $0,1,2,3$, or $4$, each with equal probability. Can you see how to combine these to get an integer uniformly distributed in $\{0,1,\ldots,44\}$?

Comment: Thanks. Is that kind like encoding a reference table?

Comment: @Brian: I’d describe it as using a reference table to interpret the outcome of the three die rolls.

Comment: I understand how you modulo the value for each roll but I don't really know how should I combine them together since we are trying to get 1 through 45?

Comment: @Brian: First, if you can get $0$ through $44$, you can get $1$ through $45$. Every integer from $0$ through $44$ has the form $9a+b$, where $a$ is $0,1,2,3$, or $4$, and $b$ is ... ?

Comment: I see, so b is actually {5,6,7,8} and then 9*4+8 = 44. And then we could use the form 9a+b+1 to represent all numbers from 1 to 45?

Comment: @Brian: Not quite: $b$ can be any of $0,1,\ldots,8$, or you won't get everything from $0$ through $44$. But yes, with that correction $9a+b+1$  will give you what you want.

Comment: May I ask you how did you get the form 9A+B intuitively?

Comment: @Brian: No, $a$ is the roll of the $20$-sided die reduced mod $5$, and $b$ is the ternary number formed from the other two rolls. \\ $45=5\cdot 9$, so I knew that if I could generate $0$ through $4$ and $0$ through $8$ uniformly, I could generate the first $45$ non-negative integers uniformly. Adding $1$ would then give me the first $45$ positive integers, which is what I want. The five choices $0$ through $4$ tell me which of the first $5$ sets of $9$ integers I have, and the other number tells me where in that $9$ I am.

Comment: There are two parts to this answer.  One is to find the minimum number of rolls.  If you roll the d6 $m$ times and the $d20$ n times, you have $6^m20^n$ rolls.  You need that to be divisible by $45=3^2\cdot 5$, so need two factors of $3$ and one of $5$, giving $m \ge 2, n\ge 1$ and he took the minimum. The second is to assign the results to $45$ classes with each class having the same number of results.  You could randomly assign the roll results to the numbers $1-45$ and then would need a table to look up which outcome matches your roll.  The modular arithmetic makes this work without a table

Comment: @Ross Thanks for the explanation! Thats absolutely more clear to me now:)

Comment: @Ross: Thanks for stepping in; I was in bed typing on a Kindle, which is not conducive to producing the clearest explanations!

Answer (score 1):

Roll the d$20$ until you get $x=18$ or less; roll the d$6$ until you get $y=5$ or less.  The number $$9y+(x{\text{ mod }}9)-8$$ is equally likely to be any number from $1$ to $45$.  To see this, note that $9(y-1)$ is uniform over $\{0,9,18,27,36\}$, and $(x{\text{ mod }}9)+1$ is chosen randomly from $1$ through $9$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with just three rolls: Roll the $6$-sided die twice, and reduce the value of each roll modulo $3$ to produce (in order) values $A, B \in \{0, 1, 2\}$. Then, roll the $20$-sided die once and reduce the value of the roll modulo $5$ to produce a value $C \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$. Then, by construction, the value of
$$(3 \cdot 5) A + 5 B + C + 1 = 15 A + 5 B + C + 1$$
is uniformly distributed over $\{1, \ldots, 45\}$ as desired.

This works as follows: Just as one can write a nonnegative integer uniquely as $$a_{n - 1} \cdot 10^{n - 1} + \cdots + a_1 \cdot 10 + a_0$$ for integers $0 \leq a_0 \leq 9$---indeed, the literal expression $a_n \cdots a_0$ is the usual decimal representation of the number, given a sequence $\{b_0, \ldots, b_n\}$ of integers $b_k > 1$, we can write an integer $0 \leq r < b_0 \cdots b_n$ uniquely as
$$a_{n - 1} (b_1 \cdots b_{n - 1}) + \cdots + a_1 b_1 + a_0,$$ where each $a_k$ is an integer $0 \leq a_k \leq b_k$. I suppose one could think of this as a sort of variable-base representation.

In our case, we want to produce an integer in the range $0 \leq r < 45 = 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 3$ (and then, by adding one, produce one in $1 \leq r \leq 45$), so we've taken the sequence $(b_0, b_1, b_2) = (5, 3, 3)$. (We could just as well have taken $(3, 5, 3)$ or $(3, 3, 5)$, but NB that this changes the coefficients of the reduced roll values: Taking $(3, 3, 5)$, for example, leads to the expression $9 C + 3 A + B + 1$.)

Alternatively, one could think of this as using the $6$-sided die to generate a random $2$-digit number in base $3$ (equivalently, an integer $0 \leq r_3 < 9$) and using the $20$-sided die to generate a random digit in base $9$ (an integer $0 \leq r_5 < 5$) and then applying the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Comment: May I ask how did you come up with each of the constants before the A,B and C?

Comment: @BrianG Sure, I've added some explanation of how this works; the short answer is that $45 = 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 3$ and the coefficients (in reverse order) are the partial products of these factors, starting with the empty product $1$: $1, 5, 3 \cdot 5$.

Answer (score 0):

Go for simplicity. Ignore the 6, 19, and 20.

1) roll the 6-sided die ONCE, unless comes up 6, then roll until it's a non-6.

2) roll the 20-sided die ONCE, unless comes up with 10 or 20, then roll again until it's neither 10 nor 20. Consider outcomes 1,11 identical, 2,12 identical, and so on up to 9,19 identical.

You would roll a total of two times a little less than 5/6 of the time, perhaps assisted by Bayesian probability to obtain an exact probability but this should not be of any great concern.

Comment: Ye, I write the same wrong answer. With this method you can get some number in more than one multiplication, by example $15=3*5$, but you can take the dupla (3, 5) or (5, 3), so you dont have the same probabilities for all numbers.

Comment: you need disable some orders, yes, and for some numbers as 12 order isnt enough cause $12=3*4=2*6$

Comment: I think @Masacroso is right

Comment: The probabilities are the same for all if you note the ordering.

1,1=1
1,2=2
1,3=3
1,4=4
1,5=5
1,6=6
1,7=7
1,8=8
1,9=9
1,11=1
1,12=2
1,13=3
1,14=4
1,15=5
1,16=6
1,17=7
1,18=8
1,19=9
2,1=10
2,2=11
2,3=12
2,4=13
2,5=14
2,6=15
2,7=16
2,8=17
2,9=18
2,11=10
2,12=11
2,13=12
2,14=13
2,15=14
2,16=15
2,17=16
2,18=17
2,19=18

that’s 1 thru 18 and is 2/5 of the total number of outcomes. 18*5/2=45

Comment: I am not making the rule as you are doing, needlessly and making it erroneous. I am fitting a method to make it work. I never suggested multiplying the numbers on the die. Are we forced to do it only that way? I read the word "represent". I didn't know represented equals multiply.

Comment: you are right @tyty, my fault

Comment: It's ok....we can reduce the pattern to:

# = 9*(a-1)+b  when b<10 and
# = 9*(a-1)+(b-10) when b>10

for a=# on 6-sided die and b=# on 20-sided die, if so designated as such.

Comment: The oddity or interesting thing about this way is you roll just 2 times, total, which I said earlier is <5/6 of the time and ends up simply being 3/4 of the time, for which you would roll 3 times once in a while, 4 times even less, 5 times rarely, but on average it should be considerably less than rolling 3 dice in every event. It would make for a nice problem to compute the probabilities for needing to roll n times and average rolls per turn in this scenario.

Comment: Devoted a few minutes to this and it might be just slightly less than 3 rolls required on average in this scenario. Perhaps a real pro mathematician could figure it out exactly.